# A topological manifold 4-dimensional with a certain fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Find a example of a $4$-dimensional topological manifold $X$ with fundamental group $\pi_1 (X, x) \simeq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_5$.

I know a action of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ in $S^3$, but it has dimension $3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the action that you know and obtain the lens space $L(5)$ whose fundamental group is $\mathbb{Z}_5$ then $M=L(5)\times S^1$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space